# How do I detect an iOS purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to detect when a purchase is made via the app store for your application?

It seems to be easy to detect an in-app purchase (ie. our server can be notified of this), however is there a way to do this for direct purchases?

If not, is there some unique identifier for the user (for example the iTunes account the purchase was made via)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIDevice`'s `uniqueIdentifier` in your app and phone home when you start up the app although that's now deprecated since iOS 5.0. There's a few ways to get around that, for example you could store a UUID in iCloud or if the user doesn't have a UUID in iCloud yet then create one and store it. This has the benefit that single users are counted rather than single devices.

Other than that, there's not really any way to determine app installs apart from just looking at your sales reports.

Answer (score 0):

There is no approved way to know exactly when an application is purchased.

But iTunes connect shows sales and trends of the previous day. 
see page 24.
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Like mattjgalloway said, you can use the UUID, but it was removed from iOS 5 because apple discourages people from tracking users with this ID. They would rather you make your own ID. It's fine if you want to track individual users, but they want to discourage you from selling that data to someone that binds those UUIDs to actual people.

This shows how to get a UUID in iOS 5.0

https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Answer (score 0):

The app Store is not great about giving specific purchase information out.  However there are several ways you can go about checking for when an applicaiton is launched.  The easiest to implement is Gooogle Analytics for ios:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html

Another would be to set up a server that gets pinged each time the application is opened with a scheme for tracking application IDs.  Unfortunately most solutions require the user to have network access at some point which cannot always be guaranteed.